# Custom error page, instead of IIS 403.503 error page after enable IP and Domain Restriction Settings?

Tags: html, web, iis

For 3 days I can not find a working version of the error page replacement, which is displayed when i Edit IP and Domain Restriction Settings, after the option is enabled Deny Action Type.

I tried to add the created custom page according to the recommendation of Microsoft, but the pages displayed when enabled in IP and Domain Restriction seem to be generated automatically and there is no possibility to replace them. Or am I wrong?

[image]

Tried to find a page template, but this template was not found in IIS folders.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I did some tests:

I created a custom page for the 403 page in IIS, and the page displayed when IP and domain restrictions are enabled is not the custom page, but an error generated by the server, as shown in the figure below.

[image]

But the magic is that I set the same custom page for the 404 page. When I access a webpage that does not exist, the custom page is displayed.

Even though I did many different tests and changed many settings, I got the same result. I guess this may be some kind of internal code setting, the error code we get does not enter the established process, so the custom page cannot be displayed.

After many attempts, I can use two alternatives.

The first method is that you can select Respond with a 302 redirect to redirect client browsers to a different URL that contains the custom error file.

[image]

The second method is to put the created 403 custom page in the %SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr\en-US directory, then open the applicationHost.config file, and replace your custom file here.

```
<error statusCode="403 " prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="Custom.htm" />
```

[image]

If you have better insights, welcome to share with me!